# Unable to set JOptionPane invisible and then back visible again

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, joptionpane, event-dispatch-thread

What I want to achieve is that

- In a certain state, a class should automatically hide dialogs displayed by other classes
- The hidden dialogs should be displayed when state of program changes

Problem:

- This does not work with JOptionPanes
- The JOptionPanes are hidden and displayed again, but then they are automatically closed, so I only see them again for part of a second

I used the following approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {

        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
            WindowEvent windowEvent = ((WindowEvent) event);
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " " + windowEvent);
            switch (windowEvent.getID()) {
            case WindowEvent.WINDOW_OPENED:
                System.out.println("Hiding");
                windowEvent.getComponent().setVisible(false);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Showing");
                windowEvent.getComponent().setVisible(true);
                break;
            }
        }


    }, AWTEvent.WINDOW_EVENT_MASK + AWTEvent.WINDOW_STATE_EVENT_MASK);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "Eggs are not supposed to be green.",
            "Inane custom dialog",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
1347602481337 java.awt.event.WindowEvent[WINDOW_ACTIVATED,opposite=null,oldState=0,newState=0] 
on dialog0
1347602481337 java.awt.event.WindowEvent[WINDOW_GAINED_FOCUS,opposite=null,oldState=0,newState=0] on dialog0
1347602481337 java.awt.event.WindowEvent[WINDOW_OPENED,opposite=null,oldState=0,newState=0] on dialog0
Hiding
Showing
1347602486377 java.awt.event.WindowEvent[WINDOW_LOST_FOCUS,opposite=null,oldState=0,newState=0] on dialog0
1347602486377 java.awt.event.WindowEvent[WINDOW_DEACTIVATED,opposite=null,oldState=0,newState=0] on dialog0
1347602486377 java.awt.event.WindowEvent[WINDOW_ACTIVATED,opposite=null,oldState=0,newState=0] on dialog0
1347602486377 java.awt.event.WindowEvent[WINDOW_GAINED_FOCUS,opposite=null,oldState=0,newState=0] on dialog0
1347602486377 java.awt.event.WindowEvent[WINDOW_LOST_FOCUS,opposite=null,oldState=0,newState=0] on dialog0
1347602486377 java.awt.event.WindowEvent[WINDOW_DEACTIVATED,opposite=null,oldState=0,newState=0] on dialog0
1347602486377 java.awt.event.WindowEvent[WINDOW_CLOSED,opposite=null,oldState=0,newState=0] on dialog0
1347602486377 java.awt.event.WindowEvent[WINDOW_CLOSED,opposite=null,oldState=0,newState=0] on dialog0
1347602486377 java.awt.event.WindowEvent[WINDOW_CLOSED,opposite=null,oldState=0,newState=0] on frame0
```

My question is, what I did to wrong? Is this per design or do I make an error, do I use the classes the wrong way? If yes, what would be the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did wrong is sleeping on the Event Dispatch Thread:

```
windowEvent.getComponent().setVisible(false);
try {
  Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Showing");
windowEvent.getComponent().setVisible(true);
```

By blocking the EDT for 5 seconds, nothing can get repainted. Use a `Timer` instead.

See the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) tutorial for more information.

Comment: I added "EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()..." around the sleep and the setting of the dialog visible again. Now it works. Thank you.

Comment: @Flo then you are still sleeping on the EDT, which blocks all UI operations. **Never** sleep on the EDT

Comment: I changed the program to use Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay) instead. So this method does not block the EDT queue and should be used in such cases. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: @Flo I was suggesting the `javax.swing.Timer` since this `Timer` will execute on the EDT. So if you want to schedule something to happen on the EDT in 5 seconds, you indeed use a `Timer` and not `Thread.sleep`